# A good SQL Structure for grouped comments with replies

Tags: sql, performance, structure, grouping

I have two tables: News, Images. Both could have comments, so i decided try to make a generic comments table. Also comments could have a reply. I solved two possible methods, but i dont know which choose in order of a good practice or good performance solution.

### Method 1 (which i am using):

News:

```
| ID | CommentGroup     |   Content | ...etc
```

Images:

```
| ID |  CommentGroup    |   Url              | ...etc
```

Considering the next image:

```
| 14 |      22          |   http://image.gif | ...etc
```

Where the comments could be these:

```
 |UserA:
 |  Coment1
 |
 |--|UserB -> UserA:
    |   Coment2
    |
    |---|UserC -> UserB:
    |   |   Comment4
    |
    |UserD -> UserA:
    |   Coment3
```

Resulting Comments:

```
| ID |  Group   |   ReplyGroup  |   Replied |   Content     |   User    |
| 13 |  22      |   NULL        |   1       |   Comment1    |   UserA   |
| 17 |  22      |   13          |   1       |   Comment2    |   UserB   |
| 11 |  22      |   13          |   NULL    |   Comment3    |   UserD   |
| 15 |  22      |   17          |   NULL    |   Comment4    |   UserC   |
```

If after commented Image14, is created a New, i decide the future comments group number by counting the max of the group column (22) so add 1 (23).

New:

```
| ID | CommentGroup     |   Content | ...etc
| 14 |      23          |   A new   | ...etc
```

Comments:

```
| ID |  Group   |   ReplyGroup  |   Replied |   Content     |   User    |
| 22 |  23      |   NULL        |   1       |   Comment1    |   UserA   |
| 30 |  23      |   22          |   NULL    |   Comment2    |   UserB   |
```

### Method 2

taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667351/sql-schema-to-allow-users-add-comments-to-various-tables) question:

News:

```
| ID | Content  | ...etc
```

Images:

```
| ID |  Url     | ...etc
```

Comments:

```
| ID |  Group   |   Type    |   ReplyGroup  |   Replied |   Content     |   User    |
```

Where type dintincts between News or Images Group.

how you think is better?
or what other solutions are possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Initially as a basic implementation I would treat everything as 'content' grouping common attributes.

```
CONTENT (
  id int primary key, 
  created_on datetime, 
  created_by int 
)
```

Then have more specific tables of the types of content

e.g.

```
NEWS ( 
  content_id int primary key foreign key references content(id), 
  article nvarchar(max) 
)
```

and

```
IMAGES (
  content_id int primary key foreign key references content(id), 
  url varchar(1000) 
)
```

and

```
COMMENTS (
  content_id int primary key foreign key references content(id),
  parent_id int foreign key references content(id) 
  root_id int foreign key references content(id),
  level int,
  text nvarchar(2000)
)
```

Each of these would have a `1:1` relationship with `CONTENT`.

`COMMENTS` would then reference other content 'directly' via the `parent_id`, the reference being either an image, news or indeed another comment.

The `root_id` in the `COMMENTS` would reference the actual image or news content (as would the `parent_id` of all 'top level' comments). This adds the overhead of maintaining the `root_id` (which shouldn't be too difficult) but will aid selecting comments for some content.

e.g.

```
-- get the article
SELECT * 
FROM content
JOIN news 
ON news.content_id = content.id
JOIN users
ON users.id = content.created_by
WHERE content.id = @news_id

-- get the comments
SELECT *
FROM content
JOIN comments
ON comments.content_id = content.id
JOIN users
ON users.id = content.created_by
WHERE comments.root_id = @news_id
```